# Python library for RSA public decryption

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I'm searching for a python library that is capable if decrypting and encrypting RSA (`RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` to be precise) with a public key. I've aleready tried `pycryptodome`, `cryptography` and `rsa` and all of them cannot decrypt using public key. I have searched through hundreds of posts, and all answers are useless, so to filter them:

1. I am not confusing a public key with a private key
2. Public decryption is possible (I was able to do it [here](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption))
3. There is no other way around. I literally need to send public encrypted messages to the server, and recieve private encrypted messages and decrypt them with the public key

Ideally it should be something like nodejs's `crypto.publicDecrypt()` and `crypto.publicEncrypt()`. Please help me to find even if not a library, but just a function that is capable of doing it. I looked through the hundreds of posts and I'm feel like I'm going insane. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want it? RSA is not supposed to be used that way. Even though mathematically that's allowed, the symmetry breaks because `d` (the private key) should be sufficiently large for RSA to be secure, while `e` is most likely something like 65537 to speed up encryption. Do you want some kind of signature?

Comment: Another point is padding, which is not clearly defined for the case "encrypting with the private key". Some libraries use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 because of the private key, some use RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 because of encrypting, and some (like the Python libraries mentioned above) do not support this at all because of that ambiguity. An RSA without padding (textbook RSA) would theoretically eliminate the ambiguity, but this rather academic RSA variant is generally not supported by the libraries for security reasons.

Comment: If you want to call it encryption that's your business. For the rest of us it's called *signing*.

Comment: @bereal I know that is totally stupid and not secure, but the thing is, I have no other choice. I am implimenting functionality of some nodejs program, and this is what it does - encrypts and decrypts with the public key. This is how server sends data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as you say indeed possible to encrypt with private and decrypt with public, the mathematical symmetry in RSA allows just swapping e/d in the keys and then calling the encrypt/decrypt functions.

This being said, I want to emphasize that I'm not a crypto expert and cannot say for certain that this doesn't compromise security.

So, you could extend the RSA-Key class with that swapped logic, use blackmagic to swap the implementation of the loaded key, and pass it to the normal functions:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey.RSA import RsaKey
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Math.Numbers import Integer

class SwappedRsaKey(RsaKey):
    def _encrypt(self, plaintext):
        # normally encrypt is p^e%n
        return int(pow(Integer(plaintext), self._d, self._n))
    def _decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        # normally decrypt is c^d%n
        return int(pow(Integer(ciphertext), self._e, self._n))

data = "I met aliens in UFO. Here is the map.".encode("utf-8")

# It's important to also use our swapped logic in encryption step, otherwise the lib would still use e&n (the private contains all 3 values).

private_key = RSA.import_key(open("mykey.pem").read())
private_key.__class__ = SwappedRsaKey
public_key = RSA.import_key(open("mykey.pub").read())
public_key.__class__ = SwappedRsaKey

cipher_priv = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
cipher_pub = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)

enc_data = cipher_priv.encrypt(data)

# Decrypt again, just a showcase to prove we can get the value back
dec_data = cipher_pub.decrypt(enc_data)

print(dec_data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works when I replace `PKCS1_OAEP` with `PKCS1_v1_5` (the server uses it), but when I'm trying to decrypt messages sended by server, `.decrypt()` always returns `sentinel` value. The craziest thing is that I know that it can work. The site I posted is able to decrypt the exact same message with the exact same key. I mean, why `pycryptodome` requires `sentinel` at all? Both site and nodejs's `crypto.publicDecrypt()` work fine without it. You got any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Never mind, I was able to fix it myself. Thanks again!

Comment: Although technically nice, this is a dangerous answer as it suggests a solution. However, the hack uses RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 padding under the hood and is therefore incompatible with libraries that apply a different padding, such as NodeJS's crypto library used by the OP. `privateEncrypt()` applies RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. Hence, the OP's problem. Of course, to get around this problem, one can continue to modify the source code (as the OP tries to do). Especially in the case of cryptography a risky way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, big thanks to Tobias K. for the short and clear answer. It worked flawlessly.

But when I tried to decrypt the server messages, `pycryptodome` kept returning `sentinel` instead of decrypted data. I decided to look into the library source  code, and check what would `.decrypt()` return if I comment out this lines in `.../Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v_1_5.py`:

```py
if  not em.startswith(b'\x00\x02') or sep < 10:
    return sentinel
```

And to my surprise it returned the decrypted message! Not sure that I didn't break something, but it works. I guess it was a bug? This is aleready fixed in their github repo, but the version is not released yet

Comment: NodeJS's `privateEncrypt()` uses RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 padding for signing that starts with `0x0001`, just because this method is meant for low level signing and not for encryption. The accepted answer, on the other hand, simply swaps the exponents for encryption and decryption but still uses RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 padding, i.e. the padding for encryption that starts with `0x0002`. The error (in case of an error the sentinel is returned) is simply caused by a padding conflict  (as expected).

Comment: @user9014097 I'd love to do it the correct way, without source code modifications, but I had aleready spent too much time trying to figure out this encryption stuff, and this is only the small part of my project. So, if it works - I'm fine with it. At least for now